# Python folder paths on synched pcs

Tags: python, file, directory, operating-system

I use .py files on two different pcs and synch the files using google drive.
As I handle files quite often with subfolders I use the complete path to read csv

```
passport = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\turbo\Google Drive\Studium\Master_thesis\Python\Databases\passport_uzb.csv')
```

However, when switching pcs I have to change the path manually since for my second pc its:

```
C:\Users\turbo\My Drive\Studium\Master_thesis\Python\Databases
```

so the only difference really is 'Google Drive' =/= 'My Drive'

Is there a work around using the complete filepath to read files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *relative* path to access the CSV instead of an *absolute* one. The [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module is useful for this. For example, assuming your script is directly inside the `...Python/Databases` folder, you can compute the path to the CSV like so, using the [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) module attribute:

```
from pathlib import Path

# this is a path object that always refers to the script in which it is defined
this_file = Path(__file__).resolve()

# this path refers to .../Python/Databases, no matter where it is located
this_folder = this_file.parent

csv_path = this_folder / "passport_uzb.csv"

passport = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

---

**Edit**: no matter where your script is located, you can use some combination of `.parent` and `/ "child"` to construct a relative path that will work. If your script is in `...Python/Databases/nasapower` then simply add another `.parent`:

```
this_file = Path(__file__).resolve()
nasapower_folder = this_file.parent
databases_folder = nasapower_folder.parent
```

Or you can use the [`.parents`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents) sequence to get there faster:

```
databases_folder = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]
```

Likewise, for the output folder:

```
output_folder = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "json"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, The script is in "C:\Users\turbo\My Drive\Studium\Master_thesis\Python\Databases\nasapower" but the csv file is in "C:\Users\turbo\My Drive\Studium\Master_thesis\Python\Databases" and the output of the script (API) should be stored in "C:\Users\turbo\My Drive\Studium\Master_thesis\Python\Databases\nasapower\json"

Comment: @Kuehlschrank see edit